How to fix fins clipping
This is my first time rigging a character in blender, i followed a tutorial so I have most of it done. The only problem I've encountered, is my character has fins on the back of their shins, so when they lift their legs they clip into the thighs. I have tried numerous times to have them pull together and kinda bunch up behind the knee, but no matter what I try it doesn't work.

I have tried the bones targetting the square bones on the left side using locked and damped track, I have tried limiting distance, none of it seems to work
Let me know if I need to add more detail like uv mapping and stuff, thanks for any answers!

You could use a driver using the "Rotational Difference between the two bones around the knee as source.
Hover the rotation channel you need to drive and hit ⎈ CtrlD to add Driver, then  RMB : Open in Drivers Editor.
From there, set the driver's type to Average Value, and the var type to Rotational Distance:

In the targets, set the armature object and the two bones around the knee.
Then, select the keyframes in the graph. Move your leg bones to the most rotations to which the fin shouldn't rotate yet, and move the keyframes so that the white dotted cursor is at zero. Then move the legs as much as it can go up, and move the second keyframe to whatever rotation you want the fin to have when the leg is that much bent.
Then move the leg back to check if there's any penetration between. If there is, add a new keyframe to deform the curve shape in between the extremes.
Finally, to be sure that the rotation can't go further, select the first and last keyframe, press V > Vector to set their handles to vector, and then ⇧ ShiftE > Constant so that the extrapolation stays constant.

The result should look like this:


Thank you so much! Gotta learn drivers now xD, either way a great help
